# I need the first two letter of the first and the last name from text box to some where in a page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I need the first two letter of the first name and the last name which will type in text box like Salman Shaikh so it will cm some where in my page as SASH i need this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K52fR/ it work done by y2ok. when what i did pastebin.com/jMN9eNYU this it wont work. i downloded jquery-1.8.0.min.js and jquery-1.8.0.js but it still dont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is live example with jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/rPTrK/

I'll paste the code in here also -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#submit").click(function() {
        var firstName = $("#name").val().substr(0, 2);
        var surname = $("#surname").val().substr(0, 2);
        $("body").append(firstName+surname);
    });        
});​
```

In case you don't know - jQuery is JS library. You can get it [here](http://jquery.com/) . Download the latest jquery release and insert it in your html/php file between the  tags, just like you normally insert js scripts.

**Attention:** You must insert my created code only after you have inserted the jQuery library, otherwise it won't work.

**EDIT: Updated to your suggested version -**

http://jsfiddle.net/pg8La/

Code -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#form1").change(function() {
        var firstName = $("#name").val().substr(0, 2);
        var surname = $("#surname").val().substr(0, 2);
        if(firstName != "" && surname != "") {
            $("body").append(firstName+surname);
        }
    });        
});​
```

**EDIT 2: Final example per your request -**

http://jsfiddle.net/K52fR/

And code here -

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="surname" />
    <br />
    <h2 id="text">WSCPP<span id="nameSurname"></span><span id="time"></span><span id="randomNr"></span></h2> 
</form>​
```

**jQuery/JS -**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#form1").change(function() {
        var firstName = $("#name").val().substr(0, 2);
        var surname = $("#surname").val().substr(0, 2);
        if(firstName != "" && surname != "") {
            $("#nameSurname").text(firstName+surname);
        }
    });        
    var currentTime = new Date(); 
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = currentTime.getDate(); var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    $("#time").text(day + "" + month + "" +year);
    $("#randomNr").text(Math.floor(Math.random()*90000+9999));
});​
```

Comment: can it genrate with out submit . like if i type and genrate automatic i need this this to <h2>WSCPP
<script type="text/javascript">
( the first name and the last name string here )
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
document.write(day + "" + month + "" +year)
document.write(Math.floor(Math.random()*90000+9999));
</script></h2>

so i will have some thing 
WSCPPSASH238201232405

Comment: can you please do that for me how i need this code betwenn this one <script type="text/javascript">
( the first name and the last name string here )
var currentTime = new Date() so i will have some thing 
WSCPPSASH238201232405

Comment: Sir, sorry to say but I am still getting confused about merging my existing JavaScript code with your provided jQuery code. i have tried to copy and replace in my file but the output is not getting shown. so can you please send me this code with the jQuery/JS attached complete example so i can start edit on that ?

Comment: Did you included the jQuery library?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>   i have downloded the jquery-1.8.0.min.js  then the code like this <script type="text/javascript">                          
jQuery(document).ready(function() { ......     });​
</script>

Comment: Have you inserted my html code also? P.S. Please paste your full code inside any of the php code libraries, so I can edit it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5ij0GRps see here. this is what i have done in single php file including <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/  
  ➥ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'>

Comment: Remove  src='script.js' from second script tag.

Comment: not working can you send me file complet in a rar including the working code php and the jquery. http://pastebin.com/jMN9eNYU see the updated one

Comment: i know that this many time i am making request. but it very important for me.

Comment: Hey, check your ajax url, it's incorrect - http://ajax.googleapis.com/  
  ➥ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js . Insert this url instead - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js

Comment: it does not work still http://pastebin.com/9uNXfEn3 is show only WSCPP and the text box you can see here http://whitesigma.com/demo/Untitled-1.php

Comment: Check if you don't have any spaces before </script> tag and after }); since you have error in console. You can view it via chrome by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + I and then going to console tab.

Comment: y2ok can you send me file created by you totally. please and there is no space between </script>

Comment: You have this character â€‹ before </script> tag. If you can open it via netbeans IDE editor, you should be able to see it. You can try removing it by removing <script></script> part and rewriting it yourself by hand if you don't have IDE editors.

Comment: can you check here , i have copy and paste the code here http://pastebin.com/5qGbMWE2 .

Comment: The code on pastebin is correct. The code from your server is not correct. Try replacing it with the one from pastebin, but paste from RAW paste data window. Or even beter - rewrite the script part of my provided code yourself.

Comment: i should i have to re-write hole code given by you?

Comment: it say error on line 20 showed in chrome

Comment: Just rewrite the javascript code that I sent to you, you have copied some hidden symbol, which is causing the problem. Be sure to delete everything between and with <script> tags.

Comment: THANKS MAN SO MUCH . I WROTE THE CODE IT GOT WORKED . THANKS  DUDE FOR YOU TIME

Comment: JUST ONE THING IN LAST THE 2 TEXT BOX U GAVE NAME= NAME AND OTHER NAME=SURNAME CAN YOU MAKE FIRST first_name AND 2ND last_name IN SCRIPT

Comment: JUST HELP  IN CHANGING AST THE 2 TEXT BOX U GAVE NAME= NAME AND OTHER NAME=SURNAME CAN YOU MAKE FIRST first_name AND 2ND last_name IN  SCRIPT

Comment: okay i have done that by my own but one thing how could i send this vaule to a CRM sales force as a text like as a inputbox . leave CRM sales force , tel me how code the vaule generate can be send as a value.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have experience with CRM sales force.

Comment: ya but how can i send this all value as one like a form . example on submit this value will send

Comment: Use AJAX Requests - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ .

Comment: Well, then you can use PHP to send request to server. But this was not your primary question. If you would like to find out how to do that, I suggest that you create a new question, in which you will get response much faster.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are POST-ing the data to some page which is why you have a tag `php`
in your question.

```
$firstname = substr($_POST['firstname'],2);
$lastname = substr($_POST['lastname'],2);
```

Comment: and so are you ;) Was I wrong? :-S

Answer (score 1):

Check following for program

http://jsfiddle.net/YNV87/

Comment: +1 for putting it into jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$_REQUEST['firstname'] = 'Salman ';
$_REQUEST['lastname'] = 'Shaikh';

$firstname = strtoupper(substr($_GET['firstname'], 0, 2));
$lastname = strtoupper(substr($_GET['lastname'], 0, 2));

echo $firstname.$lastname;
```

Comment: I +1 your answer for commenting on my answer :D But, I was first !

Comment: yap, you deserve the "correct and quickest" answer badge :-D

Comment: I wish they had one :'( Y u no +1 then?

Comment: You the star! :D I hope mods aint around :D

Answer (score 0):

Explode the string to an array.

```
$name_array=explode(' ',$name);
$first=substr(trim($name_array[0]),0,2);
$last=substr(trim($name_array[1]),0,2);
```